Can the debug console show test API results?
In a new project, I create main.test.ts, which contains assertions module:
import { assert } from "https://deno.land/std@0.224.0/assert/mod.ts";

Deno.test("Hello Test", () => {
  assert("Hello");
});
console.log('done')

If I run it in the terminal it works fine:
deno test 
Check file:///D:/Programming/test/deno/main.test.ts
------- pre-test output -------
done
----- pre-test output end -----
running 1 test from ./main.test.ts
Hello Test ... ok (0ms)

ok | 1 passed | 0 failed (2ms)

However, I would like to save a couple of key stroke and make use of the debugger. I create this .vscode/launch.json file:
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Debug tests",
      "type": "node",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "deno",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "test",
        "--inspect-wait"
      ],
      "attachSimplePort": 9229
    }
  ]
}

The debug console only shows done. I expect it to be like when I run it on the terminal. Is this possible?
